# Run console application in background until I exit from it

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, console-application

I have a windows service which monitors the file system upon starting it. Now I need to have a similar console application which should run in background. I have ported the code to the console application but I need to control this application manually from any external program.

```
MyExternalProgram
{
    Start(Myconsole)
    // Do some operations.
    Exit(MyConsole)
}
```

Similar to the above. Any input?

Comment: Does this windows service do something that couldn't be accomplished with a [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx)?  If it doesn't, then just reimplement using `FileSystemWatcher` and avoid having to spawn other applications.

Comment: Adrain, I have reimplemented FileSystemWatcher in my console application. But is there a way to keep this console application live untill i manually exit it. Because my events like OnChanged and OnRenamed lies in console app. So the application should be live untill i exit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're fine with just closing the console application, the simpliest way is to use [`Process.CloseMainWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.diagnostics.process.closemainwindow.aspx)

> Closes a process that has a user interface by sending a close message to its main window.

So call your console application with a `Process` and close it afterwards:

```
Dim p = new Process()
p.StartInfo.FileName = "c:\your\path\to\application.exe"
p.Start()
' p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden ' hide window
'
' do your stuff
'
p.CloseMainWindow()
' p.Kill() ' If window is hidden, you have to use Kill()
```

If you do not want to show the window of this application, use `p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden`, but then you have to stop it with [`Process.Kill`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.kill.aspx), which will immediately stop the process.

Another way is to use some kind of [IPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) to send an exit signal to your console application, but I assume this would be overkill for your case.

Answer (score 0):

You can launch the app with a SHELL function in VB.  You can set to minimized with a parameter:

```
Optional ByVal Style As AppWinStyle = AppWinStyle.MinimizedFocus
```

However this would merely start a instance of your app.  If some other program sent arguments to the app in a shell of its own or command line, that in most circumstances would be a separate instance (and PID).